# Stata user defined Program, Probit and Maximization Options

Tags: stata

I am having a problem calling maximization options in a user-defined program. For example, the following works perfectly:

```
sysuse nlsw88, clear
probit collgrad age grade, tech(bfgs)
```

But, when I define a function that calls on Probit, I get an error message of "option tech() not allowed". Here's the code for that

```
 program probit_test, eclass
 version 10.1
  if replay() {
  syntax [anything] [, Level(real 95) ]
  eret di, level(`level')
  }
  else {
  qui {
 syntax [varlist] [if] [in], [Level(real 95) *]

tempvar touse e1
 tempname beta var
mark `touse' `if' `in'
markout `touse'

gettoken depv vl:varlist
probit `depv' `vl' if `touse', tech(bfgs)
 g `e1'=e(sample)

 loc N=r(N)
 matrix `beta'=e(b)
 matrix `var'=e(V)

 ereturn post `beta' `var', dep(`depv') e(`e1') obs(`N')
 cap drop _d*
  }
 eret di, level(`level')
  }
 end
 ****

 sysuse nlsw88, clear
 probit_test collgrad age grade
```

Edit: I just wanted to add that this is not the actual program I am running, but a simple version that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `probit_test` program is telling Stata to behave as if it was version 10.1. In 10.1, the Broyden–Fletcher–Goldfarb–Shanno algorithm was not yet available, so it errors. Change the version to something more current (bfgs was introduced in v11), and it should run fine.